# Reducing the size of a JSON object array by stripping unwanted object attributes

Tags: json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

One of our end point is returning a JSON object array. Each object in the array has 10 attributes originally. In order to keep the array in state, I'm thinking of rebuilding the JSON array with object with minimum attribute (I need only 2).

1. Is there an elegant way to do this ES6 (Currently I'm using some loops)
2. Whether the reduction in size can gain me in terms of performance (react application and I'm supposed to store the lighter JSON in state)

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, following is a bare minimum (ES6) example,

```
const data = [
  {foo: 'foo_value_a', bar: 'bar_value_a', baz: 'baz_value_a'},
  {foo: 'foo_value_b', bar: 'bar_value_b', baz: 'baz_value_b'},
  {foo: 'foo_value_c', bar: 'bar_value_c', baz: 'baz_value_c'},
]

const compactData = data.map(({foo, bar}) => ({foo, bar}));
```

`compactData` now contains only objects with `foo` and `bar` and it reads like this, for each object of `data` destructure `foo` and `bar` and return a new object shaped with just these two properties.

The old school way (ES5) translates to

```
const compactData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {foo: d.foo, bar: d.bar };
});
```

Rule of thumb when you have an array of objects and you want the same amount of objects but with different shape you think of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)!!!

Comment: Nice use of destructuring in your arguments. You may want to highlight and explain that part of your solution.